# Joomla - PHP session in joomla disappears

Tags: php, component, session, joomla-3.9.15

I am programming a little component and module in Joomla.

My component and module reads a variable from the php session (this variable is set before for external php script).

External php script:

```
define( '_JEXEC', 1 );
define( 'JPATH_BASE', realpath(dirname(__FILE__).'/..' ));

require_once ( JPATH_BASE. '/includes/defines.php' );
require_once ( JPATH_BASE. '/includes/framework.php' );
$mainframe = JFactory::getApplication('site');
$mainframe->initialise();

//session_start();
$session = JFactory::getSession();      
$session->set('namevar', base64_encode('message'));`
```

Joomla's module and component (have the same code):

```
$session = JFactory::getSession();
$mymessage = $session->get("namevar");
echo $mymessage ;
```

The curious thing is that:
-The module works fine.
-The component does not work (and if I do a `var_dump($mymessage)` it shows `NULL`).

Moreover, this code works the time after :S

Any idea why this doesn't work the first time?

Comment: Welcome to JSE.  Please take our [tour] while you wait for support.

Comment: Are you sure the component isn't redefining the `namevar` session variable?

Comment: Hi @Lodder yes, I'm sure that I am not redefinint the namevar

Comment: After you define `$session`, I would be inclined to dump the `$session` in your both your module and then your component view, and vice versa; then you should be able to see `namevar` and its value. If that checks out; how are you including the external script?

Comment: Hello @GrantG,
I have done: echo hello world + the code of question and after define $session a var_dump.
Result: It shows empty, in other words, any error do that the firstly hello world not appears.
Without var_dump the hello world shows well.

More info: If I see the joomla debug, the var is correct in the php session.

Thanks!